# Shell: print unicode word in variable

Tags: linux, shell, unicode

I already know that I can use something like `echo -ne '\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'` to print unicode words.
But it's hardcoded. How can I use it for a variable?

Here is my script:

```
text=($1)
for i in "${text[@]}";do
    #debug
    echo "current word is ($i)"
    #code use $i goes here
done
```

The output is:

> current word is (\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87)

Directly using `echo -ne $i` does not work.

PS: If you wonder why the script input param is so weird, it came from a Perl CGI script. Maybe the Perl script is not well written, but I don't want to delve into Perl CGI's unicode support now.

Answer (score 1):

It should work with the Bash and `echo -e`. Just make sure you are really using the Bash (and not, for example on Ubuntu Linux, the dash shell):

```
$ cat script 
#!/bin/bash
foo='\xe4\xb8\xad\xe6\x96\x87'
echo -e "$foo"

$ ./script 
中文
```

Also make sure that your environment (locale) is setup to use UTF-8, for instance with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` or a different country code.

Comment: Your method is no different from what I claimed failed. We can infer from the debug output that $i maybe already a quoted string. I hope it's really that simple. I'll check it tomorrow.

Comment: I know it's not different. That's why I said it should just work.